# voltage at physical layer for data transmission at STP and UTP cables

Tags: networking, nyquist

I want to make an electronically cryptography on physical layer in the network cables.

consider a hard device which code (encrypt) the data electronically at the source system and decrypt it electronically again at the target system via changing the bits through physical layer by a electronic circuit.

what is the voltage in STP and UTP cables for data transmission?! 
in which voltage interval the '1' is represented?! and through which voltage the '0' is represented!? 
how can I read more and start studying about this problem and find standards protocols for data transmission in physical layer?!
do you know some same project?!

thanks.

Comment: Sounds intriguing in a way, but I can't really see what the purpose of this is? If using some algorithm F to encrypt known data X into unknown Y, then reversing Y to X on the other side, does it make any difference which layer you are on? In theory, you could encrypt on the physical, but still get Y on the application layer on the receiving end, and then use a corresponding algorithm to decrypt it there, couldn't you?

Comment: How ethernet is encoded depends on the standard. For instance 10 Mb and 100 Mb ethernet use different encoding. Also, the carrier is different for different ethernet speeds. You need to get the IEEE 802.3 standards.